# Using CryptDataProtect to output encrypted password for use in RDP file generates the incorrect hash

Tags: c++, rdp, dpapi

I am trying to generate an RDP file in C++ to automatically log on to a remote machine. I am using the CryptProtectData function to generate an encrypted string which can then be written to the `password 51:b` parameter of the file. However, when I then try and connect with this file, it says the password is invalid.

I have tried the following code:

```
#include <dpapi.h>
#include <sstream>

DATABLOB in ;
DATABLOB out ;
BYTE *pw_text = (BYTE *)L"to_encrypt"; // RDP uses unicode from my understanding...
DWORD pw_length = wcslen(L"to_encrypt");

in.pbData = pw_text ;
in.cbData = pw_length ;

CryptProtectData(&pw_in, L"PSW", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &pw_out);

std::stringstream ss ;
ss << std::hex ;

for (int i = 0; i< pw_out.cbData; i++)
{
    ss << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int)pw_out.pbData[i] ;
}
```

However, when I take the string contained in `ss`, paste it into my RDP file and attempt to connect it says the password is incorrect.

If I use the Powershell command to encrypt the password and use that it works, but it would be better if I can do this in C++ along with the rest of the application.

Comment: I got some of my info from the following links: [this](https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/10/18/how-rdp-passwords-are-encrypted/) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cbData` field in the [`DATA_BLOB` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa381414(v=vs.85)) is the length *in bytes*.

On the other hand, the [`wcslen` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strlen-wcslen-mbslen-mbslen-l-mbstrlen-mbstrlen-l?view=msvc-170) returns the number of *characters*.

One wide character is represented using 2 bytes, so there will be some difference.

Try multiplying the size of one character to the number of characters.

```cpp
DWORD pw_length = sizeof(*L"a") * wcslen(L"to_encrypt");
```

Comment: As simple as that isn't it... thanks, that worked :) I did `sizeof(wchar_t)`